# How to check that one String can be spelled using characters from another String?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

Example: String a = "ACAHBBA" and String b = "ABAB" should return true, since both strings can spell ABAB.

I have tried with contains(), but that only works for equal sequences.

```
// The code should look like this. 
public class task10 {
    public static boolean contains(String a, String b) {
        // check if b can be spelled using characters from a. 
        // if it can. return true. 
        // else
        return false;
    }
}
```

Posible solution?

```
public static boolean contains(String a, String b) {

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
        if (a.indexOf(b.charAt(i)) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Create two maps.... each map has a letter as the `key` and a count of how many times that character occurs in the string as the `value`.... then compare and see if map B has the same count (or more) of the letters in map A

Comment: Welcome, please read the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) fully and also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please show the actual code that you tried.

Comment: Your example and description don't match.  String a = "ABAB" and String b = "ACAHBBA" should return false, since "ACAHBBA" cannot be spelled using characters from "ABAB".

Comment: @azurefrog Ah yeah my mistake, you are correct.

Comment: thanks for answers. @azurefrog, you are correct. I edited the strings.

Comment: I also think that I found a solution. I will edit the code in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate thru one string and get the index of the character.  If >= 0, replace character with non-alphabetic character and repeat.  This algorithm presumes the need to match the correct number of characters.  For example, `hello` would return false if the character set was `helo`.

```java
    public static boolean spelledFrom(String word, String chars) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(chars);
      for (String c : word.split("")) {
         int i;
         if ((i = sb.indexOf(c)) < 0) {
            return false;
         }
         sb.setCharAt(i, '#');
      }
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: For what two strings?  In my example.  There were not enough `L's` in `helo` to spell `hello`.   I was basing it off your example with `ABAB`

Comment: Instead of setting the matched letter to #, why not just use `deleteCharAt(index)`?  The buffer's just a copy, and you aren't traversing it.

Comment: @fellekode Look at the parameter names in WJS' method, he's got them reversed from your original code snippet, but the algorithm is sound, and the it works for me.

Comment: @azurefrog That would certainly work. Didn't think about it actually.  It would be an interesting exercise to determine efficiency for real long strings.  Deleting and having the array reclaim deleted space, vs the time saved from one less character in the array to search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static boolean canSpell(String a, String b)
{
    String shorter = (a.length() <= b.length()) ? a : b;
    String longer = (shorter.equals(a)) ? b : a;

    for(int i = 0; i < shorter.length(); i++)
    {
        if(!longer.contains("" + shorter.charAt(i)))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Once you've identified the shorter string, you just need to verify that each of its chars are contained in the longer string. This solution doesn't verify if a char "has already been used", which means inserting "AB" and "ABBA" will return true. If you need to do this, you just need to delete the verified char from the longer string in every loop.